# Any easier way to integrate the complex equation

Tags: numerical-integration

```
a = 3; Tau = 100; T0 = 0.5; g0 = Tanh[2/T0];
z0 = (1 - g0) Tau;
G[q_, x_] = Exp[2 z0/(a + 1) (1 - x)^(a + 1) - g0 q q x]*g0*q*Integrate[Exp[-2 z0/(a + 1) (1 - z)^(a + 1) + g0 q q z], {z, 0, x}] + q/(q^2 + 2 z0) Exp[2 z0/(a + 1) ((1 - x)^(a + 1) - 1) - g0 q q x]
P[y_, x_ ] = Integrate[Sin[q y]*G[q, x], {q, 0, 10}]
Plot[(G[q, x]) /. q -> 0.5, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[0.5*(1-P[y, x]) /. y -> 0.1, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Here, G[q,x] is the sine transform of P[y,x] in y. When i am running this code i am getting a nice plot for G[q,x] but when i am plotting P[y,x] (which is the main function i need), it is showing a lot of errors. Is there any easier method to plot these functions, or am i missing something in the code? I tried NIntegrate as well, that is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works and much faster also.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
a = 3; Tau = 100; T0 = 1/2; g0 = Tanh[2/T0];
z0 = (1 - g0) Tau;
G[q_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
 Exp[2 z0/(a + 1) (1 - x)^(a + 1) - g0 q q x]*g0*q*
   NIntegrate[Exp[-2 z0/(a + 1) (1 - z)^(a + 1) + g0 q q z], {z, 0, x}] + 
  q/(q^2 + 2 z0) Exp[2 z0/(a + 1) ((1 - x)^(a + 1) - 1) - g0 q q x];

P[y_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] :=  NIntegrate[Sin[q y]*G[q, x], {q, 0, 10}];
Plot[(G[1/2, x]), {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[1/2*(1 - P[1/10, x]), {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]